# Compound Max Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, max

I have several tables I need to join and these in turn need to be joined to the result set from a drawing table in this drawing table each part has multiple drawing numbers and revisions. I need the maximum drawing number and then the max revision of that number for a part.

I realise I can do this by:

doing

```
select part, max(dwg_num) 
from drawingtable
group by part
```

and then embedding this is another query to get the max revision and then joining it to itself to get the other fields but it all seems a bit messy and I wondered if anyone had any ideas on a better way of doing it

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please include table structure and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank your drawingtable records per part and keep the best ranked.

```
select *
from
(
  select
    drawingtable.*,
    row_number() over (partition by part order by dwg_num desc, rev_num desc) as rn
  from drawingtable
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: This is brilliant exactly what I'm looking for! it returns the correct drawing number and revision in each case but without any duplicates